# How can get Item y position in React Native List with Map Method

Tags: react-native

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { 
Text, 
View, 
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity,
SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

//DATA

const DATA = [
    {
    id: "1",
    name: "1",
    },
    {
    id: "2",
    name: "2",
    },
    {
    id: "3",
    name: "3",
    },
    {
    id: "4",
    name: "4",
    },
    {
    id: "5",
    name: "5",
    },
    {
    id: "6",
    name: "6",
    },
    {
    id: "7",
    name: "7",
    },
    {
    id: "8",
    name: "8",
    },
    {
    id: "9",
    name: "9",
    },
    {
    id: "10",
    name: "10",
    },
    
    {
    id: "11",
    name: "11",
    },
    {
    id: "12",
    name: "12",
    },
    {
    id: "13",
    name: "13",
    },
    {
    id: "14",
    name: "14",
    },
    {
    id: "15",
    name: "15",
    },
    ];
    


export default function MainScreen() {

const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
const [y, setY] = useState(false)
return (
<SafeAreaView>
<ScrollView>
<View
style={{
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems:'center'
}}>




{DATA.map((DATA) => {

  const style = DATA.id === selectedId ? 
  {
  height:100,
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',
  width: windowWidth-40,
  borderRadius:10,
  zIndex: -1,
  backgroundColor:'green',
  } 
  : 
  {
  backgroundColor:'red',
  height: 100,
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',
  width: windowWidth-40,
  borderRadius:10,
  zIndex: -1,
  };

const onPress = () => {
  setSelectedId(DATA.id)
  };


          return (
          <TouchableOpacity
          key={DATA.id}

          onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          const { y } = nativeEvent.layout
          setY(y)
          }}

          style={style}
          onPress={onPress}
          >
          <Text>{DATA.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          );



})}



//BOX INFRONT OF SELECTED ITEM

<View style={{
  backgroundColor:'yellow',
  borderRadius:10,
  transform: [
      {
        translateY: y
      }
    ],
  position:'absolute',
  zIndex:+1,
  top:0,
  justifyContent:'center',
  alignItems:'center',
  height:50,
  aspectRatio:1
}}>
</View>




</View>
</ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
);
}
```

I create a flatlist with Map method. Every item can be selectable. Also I add a box in absolute position infront of the list.

What I want to achieve:
I want the box to be in front of the selected Item.

What I try:
I try to get the Y position of selected Item and put this Y position on the translateY of Box. But this didn't work.

My Snack code: https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/a7213a

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

ive added some changes in your code,

please check, ive did it using refs :)

Please check expo snack https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/moody-mixed-nuts

```js
import React,{useRef,createRef} from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import {  useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

//DATA

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: '2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: '3',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: '4',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: '5',
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: '6',
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    name: '7',
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    name: '8',
  },
  {
    id: '9',
    name: '9',
  },
  {
    id: '10',
    name: '10',
  },

  {
    id: '11',
    name: '11',
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: '12',
  },
  {
    id: '13',
    name: '13',
  },
  {
    id: '14',
    name: '14',
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: '15',
  },
];

export default function MainScreen() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const [y, setY] = useState(false);

   const elementsRef = useRef(DATA.map(() => createRef()));

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          {DATA.map((DATA,index) => {
            const style =
              DATA.id === selectedId
                ? {
                    height: 100,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    width: windowWidth - 40,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    zIndex: -1,
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                  }
                : {
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    height: 100,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    width: windowWidth - 40,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    zIndex: -1,
                  };

            const onPressAS = (newRef) => {
               newRef?.current?.measureInWindow( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
            console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
            console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
            console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
            console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
            console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)

            setY(fy);
        })
              setSelectedId(DATA.id);
            };

            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
              ref={elementsRef?.current[index]}
                key={DATA.id}
                // onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                //   const { y } = nativeEvent.layout;
                //   setY(y);
                // }}
                style={style}
                onPress={() => onPressAS(elementsRef?.current[index])}>
                <Text>{DATA.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
          //BOX INFRONT OF SELECTED ITEM
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'yellow',
              borderRadius: 10,
              transform: [
                {
                  translateY: y,
                },
              ],
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: +1,
              top: 0,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              height: 50,
              aspectRatio: 1,
            }}></View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Also alert the error Transform with key of "translateY" must be a number: {"translateY":false}. You know how can fix this?